# Найти объём скопившейся после дождя воды на тропическом острове

Tags: алгоритм

Текст задачи:

Предположим, в один прекрасный день вы оказались на острове прямоугольный формы.

Ландшафт этого острова можно описать с помощью целочисленной матрицы размером MxN, каждый элемент которой задаёт высоту соответствующей области острова над уровнем моря.

К примеру, вот небольшой остров размером 3x3:

```
4 5 4
3 1 5
5 4 1
```

В сезон дождей остров полностью заливает водой и в низинах скапливается вода. Низиной будем считать такую область острова, клетки которой граничат с клетками, большими по высоте. При этом диагональные соседи не учитываются, а уровень моря принимается за 0. В приведённом выше примере на острове есть только одна низина — это клетка со значением 1 в середине острова (она граничит с клетками высотой 3, 5, 5 и 4).

Таким образом, после дождя высота клеток острова изменится и станет следующей:

```
4 5 4
3 3 5
5 4 1
```

Мы видим что в данном примере высота низины изменилась с 1 до 3, после чего вода начала переливаться на соседние клетки, а затем — в море. Общий объём воды, скопившейся на острове — 2 кубические клетки.

Вот пример посложнее:

```
5 3 4 5
6 2 1 4
3 1 1 4
8 5 4 3
```

После дождя карта острова принимает следующую форму:

```
5 3 4 5
6 3 3 4
3 3 3 4
8 5 4 3
```

Общий объём скопившейся после дождя воды на таком острове составляет целых 7 кубических клеток!

Ваша программа должна быть по одному из шаблонов ниже.

На вход функции подается массив массивов, на выходе ожиается int - значения общего объёма воды, скапливающейся на острове после сезона дождей для каждого из входных примеров
Ограничения:
Размер острова N и M — целые числа в диапазоне [1, 50]
Высоты на острове могут принимать значения из диапазона [1, 1000].
Вот примеры входных данных:

```
4 5 4
3 1 5
5 4 1

5 3 4 5
6 2 1 4
3 1 1 4
8 5 4 3

2 2 2
2 1 2
2 1 2
2 1 2
```

Для приведённых выше данных, результат функции программы должен быть следующим:

```
2

7

0
```

Comment: Если во втором примере в первой строке вместо 3 будет 5, это же не изменит результат, потому что вода будет стекать по тройке, которая в 3 строке ?

Comment: Да, если есть другой путь, то вода будет стекать по нему. Стоит отметить, что по диагонали вода не течет.

Comment: При чём тут алгоритмы? Не нужно использовать этот тег для тех случаев, когда вопрос просто о нахождении способа решения какой-то задачи. Используйте этот тег только для вопросов, которые касаются теории алгоритмов.

Comment: @Александр В описании метки "Алгоритм" написано "_отмечайте вопросы где разработка или реализация алгоритма является существенной частью проблемы_". imho идеально подходит под этот случай

Comment: 1) Очевидно, что уровень воды после заливки не меньше минимального уровня на периметре острова, и не больше максимума по всему острову.
2) Предположив некий уровень воды, несложно проверить наличие максимального обрамляющего кольца высот (или его отсутствие), и при наличии посчитать объём удерживаемой в нём воды.
3) Максимум объёма среди различных уровней в указанном диапазоне и будет ответом.

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, 2 и 3 пункт поподробнее?

Comment: @Mike, но при этом не надо путать алгоритм решения самой задачи и алгоритмы программы, решающей эту задачу. Например, вопрос реализации алгоритма пузырьковой сортировки можно и нужно снабжать тегом "алгоритм". А вот если я не знаю как решать квадратное уравнение, это не значит, что нужно писать вопрос "подскажите алгоритм программы для нахождения дискриминанта" - это уже вопрос, относящийся к предметной области, а не к теории алгоритмов. Знание о том как сажать картошку - это по сути тоже алгоритм, но вопросы по агрономии всё равно не стоит на SO задавать.

Comment: @Александр тогда скажите какие теги более уместны для данного вопроса, а вообще обсуждать это в комментариях нет смысла, можете на мете задать вопрос, что входит в метку алгоритм

Comment: related: [Algorithm to solve for water accumulation given building heights](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27652073/4279)

Comment: @Mike зачем вы убрали обрамление цитированием? Всё тело вопроса же это просто цитата из задачника, а авторского тут только 1-я строка ...

Comment: @Kromster Потому, что читать его когда он желтый сложно. Цитата это или нет на смысл не влияет. Желтый полезен, когда хочешь выделить небольшой фрагмент из текста что бы например на него потом сослаться

Comment: @Mike отчасти могу согласиться. К сожалению ТС ни на что не ссылается и вопрос будет закрыт.

Comment: Так напишите ссылку на то откуда взята задача. Алгоритм не для всех очевидный и мне кажется имеет право на существование на ruSO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Возьмем две матрицы: исходную, обозначим ее `I`. И рабочую, такого же размера как исходная, но заполненную максимально возможным теоретическим значением уровня (я взял с запасом 10000), обозначим ее `W`. Далее обходим рекурсивно все поле, последовательно начиная с каждой крайней клетки острова. Рекурсивная функция на вход принимает координаты обрабатываемой клетки и *текущий уровень* воды. Если полученный *текущий уровень* ниже, чем изначальная высота клетки (берем из `I`) то принимаем *текущий уровень* равным высоте клетки. Таким образом мы получаем тот уровень, до которого может подняться вода у всех соседних клеток, если их высота ниже. В рабочей же матрице мы фиксируем минимальный уровень соседей, т.е. максимально возможный уровень для данной клетки. Напомню, изначально мы его приняли за 10000. Так вот, если уровень в рабочей матрице для клетки оказался выше, чем *текущий уровень* то принимаем его равным текущему. Таким образом мы понижаем уровень до минимально возможного при проходе через всех соседей. И еще одно важное правило: если *текущий уровень* оказался больше, чем уже зафиксированный в рабочей матрице то рекурсивный обход тут же прекращаем. Раз в `W` уровень ниже, значит мы уже приходили на эту клетку с клеток с более низким стоком и проверять дальше соседей уже нет смысла, мы там были и там максимум ниже.

Для ускорения работы можно обходить граничные клетки в порядке увеличения высоты. Тогда мы сходу зальем минимумами все доступные от них области. И при анализе от более высоких клеток повторно обходить эти области не будем.

[Пример на perl](https://ideone.com/cJYyvB)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @I;        # Исходная матрица
my @W;        # Рабочая матрица
my ($MX,$MY); # Размеры матрицы
while(<DATA>) {  # Читаем исходую матрицу
  my @row=();
  chomp;
  last if(!$_);
  push @row, $_ for split / +/;
  push @I, \@row;
  $MX=@row; $MY++;  # Запоминаем размеры
  my @row2=();      # И заполняем начальными значениями рабочую
  push @row2,10000 for(1..$MX);
  push @W, \@row2;
}
$MX--; $MY--;
# обходим все 4 стороны прямоугольника
cell(0,$_,0)   for(1..$MY);
cell($MX,$_,0) for(1..$MY);
cell($_,0,0)   for(1..$MX);
cell($_,$MY,0) for(1..$MX);

# Печать результирующей матрицы и расчет объема воды
my $summ=0;
my $y=0;
for(@W) {
  $,=" ";
  print "@$_\n";
  for my $x(0..$MX) { $summ+=$W[$y][$x]-$I[$y][$x]; }
  $y++;
}

print "RESULT = $summ\n";

# Основная рабочая, рекурсивная функция
sub cell {
  my($x, $y, $lev)=@_;
  return if($x<0 || $y<0 || $x>$MX || $y>$MY);  # Проверяем выход за пределы поля
  return if($W[$y][$x]<=$lev);    # Максимум клетки ниже или равен - мы тут были
  $lev=$I[$y][$x] if($lev < $I[$y][$x]);  # Повышаем текущий уровень, если ниже изначального для клетки
  $W[$y][$x]=$lev;    # Устанавливаем текущий максимум
  cell($x-1,$y,$lev); # И обходим всех 4х соседей рекурсивно
  cell($x+1,$y,$lev);
  cell($x,$y-1,$lev);
  cell($x,$y+1,$lev);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, постараюсь ознакомиться и разобраться :)

Comment: похоже работает. [Код на Питоне те же результаты возвращает](https://ideone.com/JcASQq)

Comment: @jfs мне было бы странно, если бы оно не работало. кстати, когда я писал ответ, то же хотел как и в вашем ответе написать, что это решение "в лоб" :)

Comment: @jfs И кажется я только что избавился от необходимости делать отдельные вызовы для всех точек периметра, добавив небольшое условие в саму рекурсию ... https://ideone.com/ks1KA2  Теперь достаточно одного вызова для произвольной точки периметра.

Comment: @Mike: да, [это тоже работает](https://ideone.com/fXTOJO)

Comment: вот [итеративная версия этого же алгоритма](https://ideone.com/6rYyAH)

Answer (score 5):

Есть простое в лоб решение, основанное на очевидных ограничениях:

- уровень воды в клетке не может быть меньше высоты клетки
- уровень воды в клетке не может быть больше уровня воды в соседних клетках

Алгоритм:

```
Для начала уровень воды во всех клетках можно установить равным наибольшей высоте.

Уровень воды в клетке на периметре острова равен высоте этой клетки.

До тех пор пока уровень воды не стабилизировался (пока его можно понизить):
  Для каждой клетки на острове,
    если уровень в ней не минимальный (если его можно понизить), 
      сравниваем уровень с соседями во всех направлениях (север, юг, запад, восток)
        если уровень у соседей меньше,
          то понижаем до уровня соседей (или до высоты самой клетки — что больше)

Чтобы найти общее количество удерживаемой воды, для всех клеток,
суммируем разницу между уровнем воды и высотой в этой клетке
```

На Питоне:

```py
NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST = (0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0)


def max_water_heldover_bruteforce(h):
    # fill initially upto the max height
    max_height = max(max(row) for row in h)
    L = [[max_height] * len(row) for row in h]

    # water level on the perimeter is equal to the height
    L[0][:] = h[0]    # North row
    L[-1][:] = h[-1]  # South row
    for column_index in [0, -1]:  # West, East columns
        # L[:,column_index] = h[:,column_index]
        for level_row, h_row in zip(L, h):  # for each row
            level_row[column_index] = h_row[column_index]  # set level

    while True:  # until the level is stable
        changed = False
        for i in range(1, len(h) - 1):
            for j in range(1, len(h[i]) - 1):
                if L[i][j] != h[i][j]:  # if not already at the minimum
                    for dx, dy in [NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST]:
                        if L[i + dy][j + dx] < L[i][j]:  # lower water level
                            L[i][j] = max(L[i + dy][j + dx], h[i][j])
                            changed = True
        if not changed:
            break

    # find how much water held over the island
    return sum((level - height)
               for row, h_row in zip(L, h)
               for level, height in zip(row, h_row))
```

Проверка для примеров из вопроса:

```py
inputs = [
    """
4 5 4
3 1 5
5 4 1
""",
    """
5 3 4 5
6 2 1 4
3 1 1 4
8 5 4 3
""",
    """
2 2 2
2 1 2
2 1 2
2 1 2
"""]

output = [2, 7, 0]
for input_text, expected in zip(inputs, output):
    heights = [[int(n) for n in line.split()]
               for line in input_text.splitlines() if line.strip()]
    got = max_water_heldover_bruteforce(heights)
    assert got == expected, (got, expected, heights)
```

[image: terminal session]

Answer (score 4):

Решения, основанные на обходе острова в произвольном порядке ([из @Mike ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/727959/23044) и [`max_water_heldover_bruteforce()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/728478/23044)), имеют временну́ю сложность `O(ncells * min(ncells, max_height))`. Их можно улучшить до `O(ncells * log ncells)`, обходя клетки, от малого уровня воды к бо́льшему. Это позволяет посещать каждую клетку только однажды.

#### O(n log n) алгоритм

Помещаем клетки на границе острова в [кучу (min-heap)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0). Уровень воды в этих клетках равен их высоте.

Посещаем все клетки из кучи в порядке возрастания уровня воды в них.
Для каждого из соседей посещаемой клетки (сверху, снизу, слева, справа) уровень воды равен
либо уровню в посещаемой клетке (так как он наименьший по свойству min-heap)
либо высоте самой клетки (так как уровень воды не может быть меньше высоты клетки)
Так как каждая клетка посещается только раз, то сразу добавляем объём удерживаемой воды (разница между уровнем воды в клетке и её высотой) в общий результат.

#### Реализация на Питоне

Вот слегка изменённое [решение от Jason Yuan](http://www.jianshu.com/p/540ee7ec725b) для задачи [Trapping Rain Water II](http://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/trapping-rain-water-ii/):

```py
from collections import namedtuple
from queue import PriorityQueue

NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST = (0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0)
Cell = namedtuple('Cell', 'level x y')

def max_water_heldover_minheap(heights, display=None):
    q = PriorityQueue()
    nrows = len(heights)
    ncolumns = len(heights[0])
    seen = [[False] * ncolumns for _ in range(nrows)]

    # enqueue cells on the perimeter of the island
    for y in range(nrows):
        seen[y][0] = True
        q.put(Cell(heights[y][0], 0, y))  # WEST side
        seen[y][ncolumns - 1] = True
        q.put(Cell(heights[y][ncolumns - 1], ncolumns - 1, y))  # EAST

    for x in range(ncolumns):
        seen[0][x] = True
        q.put(Cell(heights[0][x], x, 0))  # NORTH side
        seen[nrows - 1][x] = True
        q.put(Cell(heights[nrows - 1][x], x, nrows - 1))  # SOUTH

    # visit all cells once starting with cells with a minimum water level
    total = 0
    while not q.empty():
        cell = q.get()
        for dx, dy in [NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST]:
            x = cell.x + dx
            y = cell.y + dy
            if 0 <= y < nrows and 0 <= x < ncolumns and not seen[y][x]:
                seen[y][x] = True
                q.put(Cell(max(cell.level, heights[y][x]), x, y))
                total += max(0, cell.level - heights[y][x])
    return total
```

[Пример использования](https://ideone.com/nxcfCC).

[@David Eisenstat утверждает](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21820405/4279), что возможен линейный (`O(n)`) алгоритм, когда задача сводится к поиску [минимального покрывающего дерева](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) для плоского графа. [@Richard упоминает](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41841015/4279) что есть методы, которые применимы к задачам с триллионом клеток. См. [The Maximum Volume of Trapped Rain Water in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21818044/4279).