# Как написать счетчик островов?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, циклы

```
let arr = [[1, 0, 1],
           [1, 0, 0],
           [1, 1, 1]
     ];
```

как мне получить количество островов, тут их 2 один вверху справа(одиночный) и один большой весь последний ряд и первая колонка. я обращался к элементам при помощи 2-ого цикла.

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
for (let x = 0; i < arr[i].length; x++) {
        if(...){
      }
   }
}
```

Так вот я никак не могу придумать условие помогите.

Comment: не понятно, что такое остров ?

Comment: @Даниил Судя по картинке - область из единиц, окруженная нулями (или границей карты)

Comment: @Mike тоже так подумал, но так ли это

Comment: Вообще все не так тривиально, как просто два цикла. задача чем то напоминает https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/727877/194569 и решается такими же способами ...

Comment: Тут дело не просто в условии. Тут нужен алгоритм, и этот алгоритм не такой простой и тривиальный, как может показаться.

Comment: похожий вопрос [сколько грядок в огороде (алгоритм + реализация на Питоне)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591907/23044)

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин о дожде ничего не сказано, здесь значения только 0 и 1 — задача гораздо проще (обход в ширину работает)

Comment: @jfs Я о дожде и не писал, вы наверное кому-то другому отвечали.

Comment: @ ДмитрийПолянин верно. Это следовало @Mike адресовать.

Comment: Писал я как-то заливку, но у меня была задача уложиться в наименьшее число байт. Про скорость там лучше забыть. Но вдруг пригодится (почти без рекурсий) https://github.com/Lexx918/JS.Xonix

Answer (score 7):

Тут нужно использовать [алгоритм заливки изображения](https://habrahabr.ru/post/116374/). Логика такая:

1. Обход каждого пиксела.
2. Если он == 1, то заливаем фигуру из единиц нулями, при этом инкрементим счётчик островов.
3. В конце обхода получаем количество островов, и матрицу, заполненную нулями.

Алгоритм заливки там описан на C, но как ни странно - будет работать на JS, всего лишь заменив объявление функции, я капельку доработал, оставив только одну глобальную переменную `screenBuffer`:

```
//Recursive 4-way floodfill, crashes if recursion stack is full 
function floodFill4(x, y, newColor, oldColor = null) 
{ 
  if (!oldColor){
    oldColor = screenBuffer[x][y];
  }
  if(x >= 0 && x < screenBuffer.length && y >= 0 && y < screenBuffer[0].length && screenBuffer[x][y] == oldColor && screenBuffer[x][y] != newColor) 
  { 
    screenBuffer[x][y] = newColor; //set color before starting recursion

    floodFill4(x + 1, y,   newColor, oldColor);
    floodFill4(x - 1, y,   newColor, oldColor);
    floodFill4(x,   y + 1, newColor, oldColor);
    floodFill4(x,   y - 1, newColor, oldColor);
  }   
}
```

Comment: Я посоветую не использовать рекурсию. Для этой задачи лучше поиск в ширину а не в глубину.

Comment: @pavel есть много решений для заливки, например трассировка линиями - описанная в том-же посте по ссылке. Этот просто самый короткий и очевидный.

Comment: @Дмитрий Полянин эм, логика решения задачи до конца описана (читай после слов `Логика такая`), больше добавить нечего.- разве что реализацию в строчки 4 кода, которую оставим автору вопроса.

Comment: @Гончаров Александр Да, я уже увидел, поэтому стёр комментарий.

Comment: не пойму как вы видите эти острова, вот что тут будит островом [[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 1]]

Comment: @L11VADIS перевод строки творит чудеса, если речь об обозрении :) Только чтобы правильно обозревалось то, что у автора в вопросе - надо поменять x и y координаты (транспонировать), или записать матрицу, по другому расставив квадратные скобки.

Answer (score 3):

Эта задача называется поиск компонент связности графа.
Решается в несколько этапов:
- строим граф на основе матрицы.  Каждую клетку с 1 делаем вершиной,  соединяем её ребрами с непосредственными соседями (если они есть) 
- добавляем все вершины в массив
- поиском в глубину или ширину начинаем обход с первой вершины.  Удаляем вершины в которых побывали из массива,  добавляем их в набор вершин острова. Если обход завершён,  а массиве ещё есть вершины,  создаём ещё один остров и начинаем обход заново с первой оставшейся вершины.
Данный алгоритм имеет сложность по памяти и времени n,  работает даже для вложенных бубликов

Answer (score 3):

Набросал реализацию. В основе "построчная заливка". Чуть-чуть упростил т.к. сама заливка не нужна.

Добавил тестов. Если выполнить, то в консоли будет видно сколько их, какие прошли успешно, а какие нет.

Работает просто.

Перебираем "участки земли" слева направо и сверху вниз. Т.к. перебираем именно в этой последовательности, то для каждого участка точно знаем, что участок левее и выше - уже рассматривались на прошлых итерациях перебора. Поэтому в поиске острова учитываем только их.

Нашли участок для которого слева и сверху вода? - Это начало нового острова. Нашли землю слева? - Это продолжение найденного ранее острова. Нашли выше кусок другого острова (другого, не текущего, это важно)? - Забываем про него навсегда: он является куском рассматриваемого.

В итоге число островов равно числу всех найденных новых минус число забытых в момент поглощения.

```js
function calc(arr) {
    let rows = arr.length, cols = arr[0].length; // размеры матрицы

    let islands = 0; // порядковый номер последнего из найденных островов
    let eaten = []; // острова, примкнувшие к другим на поздних итерациях поиска

    // участок земели ..
    let left = 0, // .. слева от рассматриваемого и ..
        up = 0; // .. над рассматриваемым

    // является ли искомый остров в списке ранее примкнувших
    let isEaten = function (needle) {
        for (let i = 0; i < eaten.length; i++) {
            if (eaten[i] === needle) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    // перебираем матрицу с верхнего левого в нижний правый угол
    for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) { // построчно сверху вниз
        for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) { // а строки по столбцам слева направо
            if (!arr[row][col]) {
                continue; // пропускаем морские участки
            }
            left = col > 0
                ? arr[row][col - 1] // определяем участок земли слева
                : 0;
            up = row > 0
                ? arr[row - 1][col] // определяем участок земли сверху
                : 0;
            if (!left && !up) { // участок земли начинает остров, если слева и сверху нет земли
                islands++; // увеличиваем счётчик найденных островов
                arr[row][col] = islands; // запоминаем найденный участок
            } else if (left && !up) {
                arr[row][col] = left; // участок продолжает вправо ранее найденный остров
            } else if (!left && up) {
                arr[row][col] = up; // участок продолжает вниз ранее найденный остров
            } else if (left && up && up !== 1 && !isEaten(up)) {
                arr[row][col] = left; // участок продолжает вправо ранее найденный остров
                eaten.push(up); // а сверху к нему примыкает ранее не поглощённый остров - поглощаем его
            }
        }
    }

    return islands - eaten.length;
}

let tests = [
    [
        [
            [1, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1],
        ],
        1
    ],
    [
        [
            [1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [1, 0, 0],
        ],
        1
    ],
    [
        [
            [1, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
        ],
        2
    ],
    [
        [
            [1, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1],
        ],
        3
    ],
    [
        [
            [1, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1],
        ],
        1
    ],
    [
        [
            [1, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [1, 0, 1],
        ],
        5
    ],
    [
        [
            [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        ],
        2
    ],
    [
        [
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        ],
        2
    ],
    [
        [
            [1, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 1],
        ],
        2
    ],
    [
        [
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ],
        2
    ],
];

let result = [];
let fails = [];
console.log(`Tests: ${tests.length}`);
for (let i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
    let arr = tests[i][0];
    let expected = tests[i][1];
    let actual = calc(arr);
    if (expected !== actual) {
        result.push('F');
        fails.push(`#${i}: expected = ${expected}, actual = ${actual}`);
    } else {
        result.push('.');
    }
}
console.log(result.join(''));
console.log(fails.join(`\n`));
```

Comment: [[1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]]

Comment: @ЕгорБанин ага, спс. поправил и добавил тест в набор.

Comment: может я что-то не так понял, но код не универсален написанный Lexx918. Проверил вот на таком раскладе: [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0] [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] Результат не верный. Лично мне удалось простые варианты расстановки островов сделать Ifами elseами, а вот посерьезнее вариант увы провалился с крахом =(

Comment: @Shter проверил, 2 острова, ошибки не вижу. Какой результат у вас? (добавил ваши данные в тело ответа, можно запустить скрипт и увидеть успешно пройденные тесты)

Answer (score 0):

Предложенный @Lexx918 код не верно считает количество островов. в массиве (считает что островов 3, а по факту 4)

```
[
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
];
```

чуть доработал и упростил решение Lexx918

```js
const map = [
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
];

function findIslands(arr) {
  let rows = arr.length,
    cols = arr[0].length; // размеры матрицы

  let islands = 0;
  let eaten = []; // острова, примкнувшие к другим на поздних итерациях поиска

  let left = 0, // участок слева
    up = 0; // участок сверху

  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
      if (!arr[row][col]) {
        continue; // море
      }
      left = col > 0 ?
        arr[row][col - 1] :
        0;

      up = row > 0 ?
        arr[row - 1][col] :
        0;
      if (!left && !up) { // участок земли начинает остров, если слева и сверху нет земли
        islands++;
        arr[row][col] = islands; // нумеруем остров
      } else if (left && up && left !== up) { //верхний остров поглощен
        arr[row][col] = left;
        eaten.push(up)
      } else if (left) {
        arr[row][col] = left; // участок продолжает вправо ранее найденный остров
      } else if (up) {
        arr[row][col] = up; // участок продолжает вниз ранее найденный остров
      }
    }
  }
  console.table(arr)
  return islands - eaten.length;
}

console.log('найдено островов ', findIslands(map))
```