# Как в SVG найти область обрамляемую путями

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, svg, typescript

В `SVG` файле есть несколько путей `path`.

Мне нужно найти ту область, которая лежит между путей, обрамлена путями.

Это то, что получается в результате кнопки "Заливать замкнутые области" в `Inkscape`.

Возможно ли использовать библиотеки, предпочтительно `SVG.js` И её плагины.

**Для чего мне это надо?**

Хочу закрасить определённым образом, то что лежит внутри путей.

Пример: есть 4 пути.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо на JavaScript рассчитать, найти область внутри.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может можно и без её расчёта сделать, но нужно что-то сделать, что бы я смог раскрасить эту область на JavaScript.

Comment: Не совсем то, что вам нужно, но совсем рядом – посмотрите моё решение задачи **[нахождения пути пересечения двух путей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/926381)** (intersection).

Comment: Ага, спасибо, буду знать.

Answer (score 6):

### **Объединение нескольких  `path` в один путь.**

В первом посте итак было два совершенно разных направления ответов, чтобы не запутать людей, которые возможно придут в этот топик, я сделаю дополнительный ответ по дополнительным комментариям автора вопроса.

> рассчитав точки пересечения, я могу вычислить и куски путей до этих
>   пересечений, а потом объединить в один путь, хотя это конечно
>   математически не совсем просто.

Возьмем фигуру, составленную из четырех патчей, из предыдущего ответа:

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="840" height="594" viewBox="0 0 1488 1024" >

  <g stroke-width="3">
  
 <path id="yellow" fill="grey" stroke="orangered" d="m90.1 154.6c0 0 61.7-61.3 99.1-55.5 31.8 4.9 36 59 66.1 70.6 66.6 25.6 144.3-36.4 213.2-18 36.5 9.7 55.8 58.3 93.1 64.6 31.2 5.3 91.6-25.5 91.6-25.5l0 0" />
  <path id="black" fill="grey" stroke="black" d="m201.2 34.5c0 0-38.9 193.8-78.1 283.7-20.9 48-82.6 133.6-82.6 133.6l0 0" />
  <path id="grey" fill="orangered" stroke="grey" d="m55.5 343.7c0 0 113.1-23.2 168.1-12 61.6 12.5 105.6 79 168.1 85.6 44.3 4.7 85.1-27.9 129.1-34.5 27.7-4.1 58.4-14.3 84.1-3 35.4 15.6 75.1 88.6 75.1 88.6l0 0" />
  <path id="pink" fill="dodgerblue" stroke="hotpink"  d="m680.1 63c0 0-80.9 46.3-108.1 82.6-31.6 42.1-64.4 95-57 147.1 3.4 23.7 42.5 33.2 43.5 57 3.3 73.2-117.1 186.2-117.1 186.2l0 0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

И объединим четыре патча из первого примера в один патч, который будет иметь четыре сабпатча (подпути). Надо только строго следить, чтобы каждый подпатч начинался с большой буквы "M" (абсолютное позиционирование начальной точки подпути).
  Копируем всё в один параметр `<Path d="M....M....M....M...."/>`

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="840" height="594" viewBox="0 0 1488 1024" >
  
  <path  stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M90.1 154.6c0 0 61.7-61.3 99.1-55.5 31.8 4.9 36 59 66.1 70.6 66.6 25.6 144.3-36.4 213.2-18 36.5 9.7 55.8 58.3 93.1 64.6 31.2 5.3 91.6-25.5 91.6-25.5l0 0M201.2 34.5c0 0-38.9 193.8-78.1 283.7-20.9 48-82.6 133.6-82.6 133.6l0 0M55.5 343.7c0 0 113.1-23.2 168.1-12 61.6 12.5 105.6 79 168.1 85.6 44.3 4.7 85.1-27.9 129.1-34.5 27.7-4.1 58.4-14.3 84.1-3 35.4 15.6 75.1 88.6 75.1 88.6l0 0M680.1 63c0 0-80.9 46.3-108.1 82.6-31.6 42.1-64.4 95-57 147.1 3.4 23.7 42.5 33.2 43.5 57 3.3 73.2-117.1 186.2-117.1 186.2l0 0"
    
</svg>
```

**Расчет длины суммарного патча,- используется метод** - `getTotalLength()` `JS`

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
  <input  type="button" value="Total"  onclick="TotalLength()"/>
  <div> 
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     width="670" height="670" viewBox="0 0 670 670" > 
 
         <path id="check" fill= "none" stroke ="grey" stroke-width ="1" 
         
   d="M90.1 154.6c0 0 61.7-61.3 99.1-55.5 31.8 4.9 36 59 66.1 70.6 66.6 25.6 144.3-36.4 213.2-18 36.5 9.7 55.8 58.3 93.1 64.6 31.2 5.3 91.6-25.5 91.6-25.5l0 0M201.2 34.5c0 0-38.9 193.8-78.1 283.7-20.9 48-82.6 133.6-82.6 133.6l0 0M55.5 343.7c0 0 113.1-23.2 168.1-12 61.6 12.5 105.6 79 168.1 85.6 44.3 4.7 85.1-27.9 129.1-34.5 27.7-4.1 58.4-14.3 84.1-3 35.4 15.6 75.1 88.6 75.1 88.6l0 0M680.1 63c0 0-80.9 46.3-108.1 82.6-31.6 42.1-64.4 95-57 147.1 3.4 23.7 42.5 33.2 43.5 57 3.3 73.2-117.1 186.2-117.1 186.2l0 0" />
</svg> 
</div>
   <script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#check');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("Длина пути - " + len);
        };
  </script>
```

*Расчетная длина суммарного патча составит - `2391px`*

Когда приходит чёткое понимание, как можно сделать вручную объединение нескольких патчей в один, то наверное можно написать скрипт, который выполнит эту рутинную работу.

Comment: @Дмитрий Полянин Добавлен новый ответ

Comment: Запустил ваш пример, но что-то он не то обводит, как и в примере раньше обведены пути по отдельности.

Comment: Мне же нужно что бы центр был закрашен.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Ну да, по отдельности, это же я показал, как можно определить длину общего патча, состоящего из нескольких патчей, вы в комментариях писали, что вот бы рассчитать общую длину с помощью JS/ мне и пришло в голову, как это сделать. А до заполнения середины ещё очень далеко

Answer (score 3):

Я не представляю, как можно объяснить плагину какой путь выбрать.
 Если только с помощью утилиты, где есть пипетка, например `ColorMania` навести её на определенный участок, скопировать код цвета  `#D62728` и затем по этому параметру найти конкретный путь, который закрашен этим цветом. Но это слишком непродуктивно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я для себя выбрал другой, более короткий путь.

Допустим у нас есть svg файл средней сложности:

```html
  <svg width="175" height="175" > 
 <defs>
 <circle id="greenCircle" cx="13" cy="98"  r="10" fill="#B6FF00" /> 
 </defs>
  <g transform="translate(87.5,87.5)">
    <path fill="#1f77b4" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#aec7e8" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#ff7f0e" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#ffbb78" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#2ca02c" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#98df8a" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,83.21744517582593,-27.038987007807897L61.3431453010374,-19.93159613718411A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#d62728" d="M83.21744517582593,-27.038987007807897A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,51.4312095755914,70.7889870078079L37.91214877286452,52.18159613718411A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,61.3431453010374,-19.93159613718411Z"></path>
    <path fill="#ff9896" d="M51.4312095755914,70.7889870078079A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,-51.43120957559139,70.7889870078079L-37.91214877286451,52.18159613718411A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,37.91214877286452,52.18159613718411Z"></path>
    <path fill="#9467bd" d="M-51.43120957559139,70.7889870078079A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,-83.21744517582594,-27.038987007807886L-61.34314530103741,-19.9315961371841A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,-37.91214877286451,52.18159613718411Z"></path>
    <path fill="#c5b0d5" d="M-83.21744517582594,-27.038987007807886A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,-1.607348923880901e-14,-87.5L-1.1848457781750641e-14,-64.5A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,-61.34314530103741,-19.9315961371841Z"></path>
  </g> 
  
<use xlink:href="#greenCircle"  transform="rotate(-10 87.5 87.5)" /> 
<use xlink:href="#greenCircle"  transform="rotate(62 87.5 87.5)" /> 
<use xlink:href="#greenCircle"  transform="rotate(134 87.5 87.5)" /> 
<use xlink:href="#greenCircle"  transform="rotate(206 87.5 87.5)" /> 
<use xlink:href="#greenCircle"  transform="rotate(278 87.5 87.5)" />  

</svg>
```

Ставлю единичку перед "М" в формуле пути `d="1M83.21744517582593` и этот конкретный путь исчезает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь я знаю какой конкретный путь отвечает за конкретную часть изображения.
Если нужно одновременно перекрасить много участков с одинаковым цветом, то в Notepad++ делаю поиск с одновременной заменой по этому параметру `#d62728`

### **update**

по результатам уточнений в вопросе

Взял ваш эскиз в качестве образца для SVG файла

*Ниже код svg*

Патчи не заполнены цветом. Только закрашены строки.

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="840" height="594" viewBox="0 0 1488 1024" version="1.1" >

  <g stroke-width="2">
  
 <path id="yellow" fill="none" stroke="orangered" d="m90.1 154.6c0 0 61.7-61.3 99.1-55.5 31.8 4.9 36 59 66.1 70.6 66.6 25.6 144.3-36.4 213.2-18 36.5 9.7 55.8 58.3 93.1 64.6 31.2 5.3 91.6-25.5 91.6-25.5l0 0" />
  <path id="black" fill="none" stroke="black" d="m201.2 34.5c0 0-38.9 193.8-78.1 283.7-20.9 48-82.6 133.6-82.6 133.6l0 0" />
  <path id="grey" fill="none" stroke="grey" d="m55.5 343.7c0 0 113.1-23.2 168.1-12 61.6 12.5 105.6 79 168.1 85.6 44.3 4.7 85.1-27.9 129.1-34.5 27.7-4.1 58.4-14.3 84.1-3 35.4 15.6 75.1 88.6 75.1 88.6l0 0" />
  <path id="pink" fill="none" stroke="hotpink"  d="m680.1 63c0 0-80.9 46.3-108.1 82.6-31.6 42.1-64.4 95-57 147.1 3.4 23.7 42.5 33.2 43.5 57 3.3 73.2-117.1 186.2-117.1 186.2l0 0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Следующий пример с заполнением цветом.

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="840" height="594" viewBox="0 0 1488 1024" version="1.1" style="border:1px solid red;">

  <g stroke-width="3">
  
 <path id="yellow" fill="grey" stroke="orangered" d="m90.1 154.6c0 0 61.7-61.3 99.1-55.5 31.8 4.9 36 59 66.1 70.6 66.6 25.6 144.3-36.4 213.2-18 36.5 9.7 55.8 58.3 93.1 64.6 31.2 5.3 91.6-25.5 91.6-25.5l0 0" />
  <path id="black" fill="grey" stroke="black" d="m201.2 34.5c0 0-38.9 193.8-78.1 283.7-20.9 48-82.6 133.6-82.6 133.6l0 0" />
  <path id="grey" fill="orangered" stroke="grey" d="m55.5 343.7c0 0 113.1-23.2 168.1-12 61.6 12.5 105.6 79 168.1 85.6 44.3 4.7 85.1-27.9 129.1-34.5 27.7-4.1 58.4-14.3 84.1-3 35.4 15.6 75.1 88.6 75.1 88.6l0 0" />
  <path id="pink" fill="dodgerblue" stroke="hotpink"  d="m680.1 63c0 0-80.9 46.3-108.1 82.6-31.6 42.1-64.4 95-57 147.1 3.4 23.7 42.5 33.2 43.5 57 3.3 73.2-117.1 186.2-117.1 186.2l0 0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Видите как `fill` работает, если каждый конкретный `path` не замкнут,- распределение цвета идет по обе стороны от линии. Рассчитать точки пересечения патчей это одно, а вот вычислить, как будет распределен цвет, это уже более трудная задача и я не знаю, есть ли у неё простое решение. Так как просто рассчитать скриптом площадь такой криволинейной фигуры и то довольно сложная задача.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вы меня немного не поняли, возможно у меня не получилось сразу ясно сформулировать вопрос, я обновил текст вопроса, что бы стало более понятно. Мне нужно эту область рассчитать не в редакторе, а на JavaScript. То есть это не разовая операция, а мне нужно рассчитывать на лету на странице.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин этот вариант, что показали вы невозможен теоретически. Как вы будете красить, что вы будете красить? свойство `fill` принадлежит к одному патчу, а не к совокупности патчей

Comment: Вот про то и речь. Но зная сами пути, можно математически рассчитать внутреннюю часть. Вполне возможно есть какие-то JS библиотеки для этого. Например в `svg.js` есть функционал позволяющий найти точки пересечения путей, но это не то что нужно.

Comment: Ваш ответ навёл меня на мысли, что рассчитав точки пересечения, я могу вычислить и куски путей до этих пересечений, а потом объединить в один путь, хотя это конечно математически не совсем просто. Для путей состоящих из прямых линий, это решаемая задача, но если участвуют сплайны, тогда дело усложняется, и это получается уже реально непростой алгоритм.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Добавил ещё один ответ, может как-то поможет вам продвинуться в решении нетривиальной задачи.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Потеряли интерес к теме? Поступило два новых ответа и никакой реакции :)

Comment: Я почему-то не видел ответов, может пропустил... спасибо что напомнили

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин ну вот, как раз я нашел, то промежуточное решение, о котором вы писали в комментариях чуть выше - найдена общая длина сплайнов

Comment: Хоть решение алгоритма я и не нашёл согласно вопросу, но на данный момент понял как мне решить мою задачу, я буду подходить немного по-другому. В очередной раз понимаю, насколько общение с другими людьми помогает выйти из тупика и застоя, и продвинуться в ситуации, даже в том случае если прямого ответа и нет.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к ответу @Alexandr_TT ( суть которого в том, что несколько path-ей нужно собрать в один). Вижу довольно простое решение, которое однако может показаться математически не самым правильным:

1. Растеризуем картинку с помощью `canvas`.
2. Выполняем любую функцию заливки изображения цветом X (например самую простую [постил здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755697#755707)) в любой точке предполагаемой фигуры.
3. Перебираем все пикселы цвета X в canvas, переводим координаты пикселов в координаты svg.
4. Для каждого пиксела перебираем расстояние до каждой вершины в svg - и если оно меньше порогового (порог - размер  пиксела x 2 в системе координат  SVG) - значит мы нашли новую вершину нашей новой области!
5. Осталось только последовательно соединить все найденные вершины - делается это просто, так как все отрезки записаны в path-ах. Если отрезок не найден - берётся крайняя ближайшая точка вне path-а: таким образом образуются стыки разных path-ей.

Хорош своей простотой. Алгоритм #2:

1. От конкретной точки предполагаемой фигуры проводятся воображаемые отрезки(назову их "лучи") до каждой из вершин каждого path-а.
2. Для каждого луча проверяется пересечение с каждым отрезком каждого path-а ([например таким алгоритмом проверки пересечения отрезков](https://habrahabr.ru/post/267037/)).
3. Если луч не пересёк ни одного отрезка, бинго, вершина на конце луча - это одна из вершин фигуры, которую мы вычисляем. Таким образом перебрав все лучи мы получаем все вершины новой фигуры кроме угловых.
4. Угловые вершины вычисляются отдельно пересечением угловых отрезков (т.к. они не относятся ни к одному из путей).
5. Дальше сооственно все - последовательное расположение вершин будет новой фигурой.

Хорош точностью. Есть одно большое но - **заполнит только выпуклые фигуры** - это решится усложнением алгоритма. В трёхмерной графике такие алгоритмы нередки для `collision detection`, это целая история - и оптимизировать их быстродействие можно годами :)

Comment: сразу оговорюсь, я не специалист в той области знаний, которую вы затронули в своем ответе, поэтому я не могу оценить по достоинству, ни правильность подхода, ни красоту ваших решений, но могу оценить ваше стремление решить вопрос (+) Надеюсь у вас не исчезнет стимул для поиска практического решения в виде скрипта, который хотел получить в ответе автор вопроса.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT к сожалению качественный отлаженный скрипт с таким алгоритмом - это много времени, у меня бы ушло день-два. То есть явно, поскольку готового алгоритма нет - это не сюда, а на фриланс.ру :) Работал раньше и с векторной и с растровой графикой(например делал распознавание изображений исключительно в JS на сегментации без ИНС), поэтому вопрос заинтересовал. В графике подобные задачи нередки, и всё что придумал - изложил, помог чем мог: а дальше уже дело автора вопроса, тратить день на реализацию алгоритма векторного заполнения, или же нет.

Comment: Спасибо, за ваше решение. Подумаю можно ли использовать. У меня не любые линии а имеют некоторую структуру. и я буду её использовать для объединения путей. Если бы линии состояли из отрезков я бы зная структуру легко бы сделал общий путь по ним, но вот со сплайнами посложнее. Как урезать угловые сплайны при пересечении. Вообще не уверен что часть сплайна является сплайном... надо математически посмотреть. И даже если является там придётся эти угловые сплайны пересчитывать.