# Как получить путь пересечения двух путей SVG программно?

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, snapsvg

**Нужно пересечь два SVG-пути и получить путь, представляющий их пересечение.**

Не важно, будет это работать в браузере или в Node.js.
Нужно именно пересечение, использование `clip-path` не подходит.
Если после пересечения вдруг понадобится `transform`, то не страшно (сам его уберу).

Думаю, для этого уже есть какая-нибудь библиотека, но нашёл только

- [svg-intersections](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-intersections) - возвращает массив точек пересечения, а мне надо `path`
- [path-intersection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-intersection) - что-то у меня вообще не взлетела - всегда получается пустой массив
- [snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.path.intersection) - вроде даёт то-то полезное, но я не пойму, как это использовать

---

Например, при пересечении этих путей:

```
M 24.379464,51.504463 23.434524,23.156249 38.742559,12.572916 c 0,0 29.860118,-9.0714281 17.00893,0.755953 -12.851191,9.82738 13.229166,19.465774 13.229166,19.465774 z
m 32.883928,0.28869028 c 0,0 -15.686011,1.51190452 -8.504463,7.18154712 7.181546,5.6696426 50.270836,30.0491076 26.458332,42.3333336 -23.8125,12.284226 47.058036,14.174107 47.058036,14.174107 z
```

должно получиться (примерно):

```
M 43.943359 11.123047 C 40.995759 11.900151 38.742188 12.572266 38.742188 12.572266 L 35.236328 14.996094 C 44.091432999999995 21.21816 55.052161 29.822765 57.455078 37.628906 L 66.939453 33.650391 63.632812 30.410156 C 58.77426 27.95814 52.364322 23.85552 52.214844 19.224609 L 43.943359 11.123047 z
```

Вот интерактивный сниппет с путями из примера (на цвета внимание не обращать - они просто для наглядности) - надо получить путь <kbd>Пересечение</kbd> из `#path1` и `#path2`:

```css
svg { width: 10em; width: 100vmin; outline: 1px dotted blue; display: none; }
input { display: none; }
label { width: 10em; float: left; clear: left; cursor: pointer; line-height: 2em; margin: 0 .5em .25em 0; padding: 0 .25em; border: 1px solid; }
:checked + * + * + label { background: antiquewhite; color: blue; }
:checked + * + * + * + * + * + svg { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<input type=radio name=svg id=in checked>
<input type=radio name=svg id=out>
<input type=radio name=svg id=cp>

<label for=in>Данные</label>
<label for=out>Пересечение</label>
<label for=cp>Обрезка</label>

<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="22 0 76 64">
  <path id="path1"
    style="fill:rgba(255,0,0,.5); stroke:red;stroke-width:0.26458332px;"
    d="M 24.379464,51.504463 23.434524,23.156249 38.742559,12.572916 c 0,0 29.860118,-9.0714281 17.00893,0.755953 -12.851191,9.82738 13.229166,19.465774 13.229166,19.465774 z"
  />
  <path id="path2"
    style="fill:rgba(0,255,0,.5);stroke:green;stroke-width:0.26458332px;"
    d="m 32.883928,0.28869028 c 0,0 -15.686011,1.51190452 -8.504463,7.18154712 7.181546,5.6696426 50.270836,30.0491076 26.458332,42.3333336 -23.8125,12.284226 47.058036,14.174107 47.058036,14.174107 z"
  />
</svg>

<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="22 0 76 64">
  <path
    style="fill:rgba(0,0,255,.5);stroke:blue;stroke-width:0.26458332px;"
    d="M 43.943359 11.123047 C 40.995759 11.900151 38.742188 12.572266 38.742188 12.572266 L 35.236328 14.996094 C 44.091432999999995 21.21816 55.052161 29.822765 57.455078 37.628906 L 66.939453 33.650391 63.632812 30.410156 C 58.77426 27.95814 52.364322 23.85552 52.214844 19.224609 L 43.943359 11.123047 z"
  />
</svg>

<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="22 0 76 64">
  <clipPath id="clip2">
    <use xlink:href="#path2" />
  </clipPath>
  <use xlink:href="#path1" clip-path="url(#clip2)" />
</svg>
```

**Пример со Snap.svg**

```js
var p1 = "M 24.379464,51.504463 23.434524,23.156249 38.742559,12.572916 c 0,0 29.860118,-9.0714281 17.00893,0.755953 -12.851191,9.82738 13.229166,19.465774 13.229166,19.465774 z"
var p2 = "m 32.883928,0.28869028 c 0,0 -15.686011,1.51190452 -8.504463,7.18154712 7.181546,5.6696426 50.270836,30.0491076 26.458332,42.3333336 -23.8125,12.284226 47.058036,14.174107 47.058036,14.174107 z"

var intersection = Snap.path.intersection(p1, p2)

console.log(intersection)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

```html
<script src=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js></script>
```

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/50011373/4928642)

Comment: Qwertiy, нашел такую штуку. Сам не разобрался, но вроде работает. Ты просто лучше меня разберешься http://paperjs.org/examples/path-intersections/

Comment: Я задавал ранее такой же вопрос, и ответа так и не было - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772089/Как-в-svg-найти-область-обрамляемую-путями

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, у тебя вопрос несколько другой и выглядит сложнее моего)

Comment: @Air, там снова точки пересечения, а не пути...

Comment: @Qwertiy да, вижу, получается тебе нужна математика множеств - пересечение, ещё есть операции суммы и разницы. Мне тоже эта тема интересна.

Comment: @Air, зачем форматирование поменял?

Comment: @Qwertiy, код форматировал по привычке...))  Ну имея точки пересечения, можно же путь из точем выложить?  Или я вопрос не понял...

Comment: @Air, там кривые безье, а не ломаные - я по таким не умею строить...

Comment: @Qwertiy  я просто из за интереса спрошу , а  для чего этот головняк ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, да тут с иконками химичим немного...

Comment: @Arthur, ух ты, только увидел. А в честь чего конкурс?)

Comment: @Qwertiy, не нужна мне больше репутация, нужно вернуть сообществу, нет смысла оставаться на русском so, лично для меня, поэтому нужно уделить время сложным вопросам, типа такого

Answer (score 9, accepted):

После многодневных поисков я всё же нашёл решение там, где я его вообще не ожидал увидеть, а именно **[вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23259192)**. Этот ответ подтолкнул меня вспомнить то, что давно я это видел на PaperJS в булевых операциях (Boolean Operations).

У PaperJS есть 5 различных булевых операций: `exclude`, `subtract`, `unite`, `intersect`, `divide` и мы будем использовать одну из них под названием `intersect`. Эти операции являются также и одноимёнными функциями и все возвращают новый `item` объект, из которого можно посредством функции `exportSVG()` получить настоящий `SVG Path element`, который содержит путь пересечения наших путей.

**Пример правильного решения**

```js
paper.install(window);
window.onload = function()
{
    paper.setup('canvas');

    var p1 = 'M 24.379464,51.504463 23.434524,23.156249 38.742559,12.572916 c 0,0 29.860118,-9.0714281 17.00893,0.755953 -12.851191,9.82738 13.229166,19.465774 13.229166,19.465774 z',
        p2 = 'm 32.883928,0.28869028 c 0,0 -15.686011,1.51190452 -8.504463,7.18154712 7.181546,5.6696426 50.270836,30.0491076 26.458332,42.3333336 -23.8125,12.284226 47.058036,14.174107 47.058036,14.174107 z',
        path1 = new Path(p1),
        path2 = new Path(p2);

    path1.fillColor = 'rgba(255,0,0,.5)';
    path1.position = new Point(25, 25);

    path2.fillColor = 'rgba(0,255,0,.5)';
    path2.position = new Point(40, 25);
    
    var result = path2.intersect(path1);
    result.selected = true;
    result.fillColor = '#77f';

    //exportSVG() docu: http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#exportsvg
    var svgPathElement = result.exportSVG(),
        dPath = svgPathElement.getAttribute('d');
    
    document.querySelector('path').setAttribute('d', dPath);

    var output = document.querySelector('#output');
    output.innerHTML = '<pre>' + dPath + '</pre>';
    output.innerHTML += '<xmp>' + svgPathElement.outerHTML + '</xmp>';
};
```

```css
table
{
    margin-left:14px;
    padding-left:14px;
    border-left:1px solid gray;
    display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.0/paper-full.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="75" height="75" resize></canvas>
<table><tr><td><b>Наш путь пересечения в виде отдельного SVG:</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <svg width="75" height="75" viewBox="0 0 75 75">
    <path fill="rgba(0,0,255,.5)" d=""/>
    </svg>
</td></tr></table>

<div id="output"></div>
```

**Смотрите также:**

- Пример [PaperJS Boolean Operations: exclude, subtract, unite, intersect, divide](http://paperjs.org/examples/boolean-operations/)
- [PaperJS примеры](http://paperjs.org/examples/)
- [PaperJS Reference (документация)](http://paperjs.org/reference/global/)

Answer (score 5):

1. Вот [jsclipper](http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/6.1.3.1/index.html)
2. Жуткое извращение, но работает: для одного проекта у меня было прикручено растровое смешение 2х цветных зон, выделение смешанного цвета с его последующей обратной трассировкой в вектор.

PS: трассировка - potrace, если это кому-то интересно - пишите

Comment: Интересно, но оно же только для многоугольников?

Comment: при таком преобразовании линия превращается в полигон, однако там где я это использую, мало того, мне так и надо, получается merge множества фигур

Comment: Возможно вы ещё не видели моё решение этого вопроса. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, я думаю вам тоже будет увлекательно это увидеть. Оно расположено сверху вашего ответа.

Comment: Да,спасибо, я даже пытался использовать paperjs для своего приложения, кстати гуглеж svg path Boolean operations, выдаёт много всего интересного, а если вы так прозрачно намекаете на vote up, то пожалуйста, мой шестой )) бом шанкар

Comment: Благо дарю вам за «+»! Да, надо будет изучить ответы от Google. Я думал просто вам будет увлекательно, так как вы что-то подобное тоже делаете. А что за приложение? Не забывайте в ответе указывать моё имя (@имя), иначе я сообщение от вас не получу.

Comment: @Bharata приложение пока находится в разработке, это будет часть портала, на котором пользователи-арендаторы площадей и владельцы зданий могут нарисовать поверх карты в 2д режиме план здания. А потом это представляется уже на трехмерной карте.

Comment: @Bharata ссылку к сожалению пока не могу дать, если интересно могу видео записать

Comment: Если вам захочется сделать такое видео, то я бы с удовольствием посмотрел бы его.

Comment: @Bharata https://youtu.be/SEqZHPaz6Tg, вот тут очень поверхностно снял

Comment: @Bharata в первом иструменте рисуются svg этажей, логических зон и мета информации, а в просмотрщике из этого на лету строится 3d моделька, backendless

Comment: Вот это да! Мне очень понравилось! Design тоже отличный и приятный! Успехов вам больших и удачи в вашем деле! А векторный редактор сами писали или чей-то прикрутили? Также увлекательно про 3d на лету – сами всё писали или готовое такое есть?

Comment: @Bharata редактор, fabric js, но он не подошёл, много чего переписано на d3, в итоге я откажусь от него, конвертирование вектора в модель - базовые алгоритмы конечно же придумал не я, но много чего пришлось скрестить, отдебажить и подкрутить, там много стадий, трассировка, симплификация, растеризация, поиск контуров, потом ещё шейдеры всякие, много чего..

Comment: @Bharata спасибо за похвалу)

Comment: @Bharata основная фишка и сложность это привязка всего этого к карте

Comment: Вы можете, если конечно есть желание, это всё подробно описать – я буду очень рад узнать как вы всё это сделали. Мне очень увлекательно! Но это не просьба – только если сами хотите.

Comment: @Bharata непосредственно svg path в последовательность вершин для 3д рендеринга получается через встроенную three.js функцию. Сам рендеринг собственно тоже на three js, но оно нарисовано поверх mapbox-gl-js оверлеем.  Трансформации карты и 3д сцены синхронизированны.

Comment: @Bharata а получается этот path за счёт трассировки растровой картинки, которая на входе состоит из множества векторных фигур.

Comment: @Bharata на so не отправить личное сообщение, похвастаюсь тут: я загрузил видосов последних работ на канал...

Comment: Ого! Посмотрю обязательно! А вы случайно не знаете где найти скрипт "cartoon filter" на JavaScript без WebGL? Мне нужно для 2D снимков (3D не пойдут), но я пока не нашёл.

Comment: @Bharata если я правильно вас понял, то вам нужно векторизовать растр. Посмотрите на js версию potrace https://github.com/kilobtye/potrace/

Comment: Это совсем не то, к сожалению. Мне нужно приблизительно или полностью **[вот такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndkcf.png)**. Видео ваши я посмотрел. Похвалить могу – вы молодец! Хорошая работа! Только без объяснений не совсем понятно.

Comment: @Bharata вот еще посмотрите https://github.com/jankovicsandras/imagetracerjs

Answer (score 4):

Идея следующая:

- Для каждой точки пересечения делим пересекающиеся сегменты на 2 фрагмента каждый
- Немного отклоняясь от точки пересечения в каждую из сторон, проверяем, какая сторона оказалась внутри другого пути
- Выбираем нужные фрагменты, при необходимости меняем начало и конец местами
- Сегменты, не участвующие в пересечении добавляем просто так в соответствии с тем, кому принадлежал последний фрагмент
- Надо как-то осторожно обработать случаи, когда сегмент пересекается многократно

Пока есть только незаконченная попытка вычислить первую точку:

```js
var p1 = "M 24.379464,51.504463 23.434524,23.156249 38.742559,12.572916 c 0,0 29.860118,-9.0714281 17.00893,0.755953 -12.851191,9.82738 13.229166,19.465774 13.229166,19.465774 z"
var p2 = "m 32.883928,0.28869028 c 0,0 -15.686011,1.51190452 -8.504463,7.18154712 7.181546,5.6696426 50.270836,30.0491076 26.458332,42.3333336 -23.8125,12.284226 47.058036,14.174107 47.058036,14.174107 z"

function binSearch(l, r, f, eps) {
  while (1) {
    var m = (l+r) / 2
    if (f(m) > 0) r = m; else l = m;
    if (r-l < eps) return m
  }
}

var intersection = Snap.path.intersection(p1, p2)
var cx = intersection[0].x, cy = intersection[0].y
var b1 = intersection[0].bez1, b2 = intersection[0].bez2

var pp1 = `M${b1[0]},${b1[1]} C ${b1.slice(2).join(" ")}`
var pp2 = `M${b2[0]},${b2[1]} C ${b2.slice(2).join(" ")}`

var t1 = intersection[0].t1
var t2 = intersection[0].t2

function selectFragment(p, b, t, dt, x, y, isSecond) {
  var bp = `M${b[0]},${b[1]} C ${b.slice(2).join(" ")}`
  var len = Snap.path.getTotalLength(bp)
  
  // Почему-то значение intersection[0].t1 неточно работает в findDotsAtSegment
  // Ищем точное бинпоиском, но это только для выбора сегмента
  // Обрезать путь надо по оригинальному значению
  var tt = binSearch(0, 1, t => Snap.path.findDotsAtSegment(...b, t).x - x, dt / 4)
  
  var ptl = Snap.path.findDotsAtSegment(...b, tt - dt)
  var ptr = Snap.path.findDotsAtSegment(...b, tt + dt)
  
  var isl = Snap.path.isPointInside(p, ptl.x, ptl.y)
  var isr = Snap.path.isPointInside(p, ptr.x, ptr.y)
  
  if (isl ^ isr) {
    if (isl) {
      var l = 0, r = t * len   // Берём начало пути b
    } else {
      var l = t * len, r = len // Берём конец пути b
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error("Both points are on the same side")
  }
  
  var pt1 = Snap.path.findDotsAtSegment(...b, l)
  var pt2 = Snap.path.findDotsAtSegment(...b, r)
  
  // не работает
  ////// Для второго фрагмента точка пересечения должна быть в начале, а для первого - в конце
  ////if (isSecond ^ (Math.abs(pt1.x-x)+Math.abs(pt1.y-y) > Math.abs(pt2.x-x)+Math.abs(pt2.y-y))) {
  ////  [l, r] = [r, l] // Нужно перевернуть фрагмент
  ////}

  // getSubpath может вернуть начало и конец неточно, поэтому
  // начальную M меняем на L чтобы исправить его начало - пока не готово
  var res = Snap.path.getSubpath(bp, l, r) // .replace('M', 'L')
  
  // Добавляем переход в нужную точку через L чтобы исправить неточности
  return res // isSecond ? `L ${x},${y} ${res}` : `${res}`
}

// Самый первый фрагмент не должен начинаться с линии - возвращаем M
var p1i = selectFragment(p1, b2, t2, .001, cx, cy, false).replace('L', 'M')
var p2i = selectFragment(p2, b1, t1, .001, cx, cy, true)

console.log(p1i)
console.log(p2i)

document.getElementById('res').setAttribute('d', p1i + p2i)

//[
//  {
//    "x": 35.21843116823025,
//    "y": 15.00935009348013,
//    "t1": 0.769785747695916,
//    "t2": 0.25341822203708086,
//    "segment1": 2,
//    "segment2": 2,
//    "bez1": [
//      23.434524,
//      23.156249,
//      23.434524,
//      23.156249,
//      38.742559,
//      12.572916,
//      38.742559,
//      12.572916
//    ],
//    "bez2": [
//      24.379464999999996,
//      7.4702374,
//      31.561010999999997,
//      13.139880000000002,
//      74.650301,
//      37.519345,
//      50.837796999999995,
//      49.803571000000005
//    ]
//  },
//  ...
//]
```

```css
svg { width: 10em; width: 100vmin; outline: 1px dotted blue; display: none; }
input { display: none; }
label { width: 10em; float: left; clear: left; cursor: pointer; line-height: 2em; margin: 0 .5em .25em 0; padding: 0 .25em; border: 1px solid; }
:checked + * + * + * + label { background: antiquewhite; color: blue; }
:checked + * + * + * + * + * + * + * + svg { display: inline-block; }
/* svg:last-of-type { display: inline-block; position: absolute; transform: translateX(-100%); } /**/
```

```html
<script src=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js></script>

<input type=radio name=svg id=in checked>
<input type=radio name=svg id=out>
<input type=radio name=svg id=cp>
<input type=radio name=svg id=int>

<label for=in>Данные</label>
<label for=out>Пересечение</label>
<label for=cp>Обрезка</label>
<label for=int>Вычисленное</label>

<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="22 0 76 64">
  <path id="path1"
    style="fill:rgba(255,0,0,.5); stroke:red;stroke-width:0.26458332px;"
    d="M 24.379464,51.504463 23.434524,23.156249 38.742559,12.572916 c 0,0 29.860118,-9.0714281 17.00893,0.755953 -12.851191,9.82738 13.229166,19.465774 13.229166,19.465774 z"
  />
  <path id="path2"
    style="fill:rgba(0,255,0,.5);stroke:green;stroke-width:0.26458332px;"
    d="m 32.883928,0.28869028 c 0,0 -15.686011,1.51190452 -8.504463,7.18154712 7.181546,5.6696426 50.270836,30.0491076 26.458332,42.3333336 -23.8125,12.284226 47.058036,14.174107 47.058036,14.174107 z"
  />
</svg>

<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="22 0 76 64">
  <path
    style="fill:rgba(0,0,255,.5);stroke:blue;stroke-width:0.26458332px;"
    d="M 43.943359 11.123047 C 40.995759 11.900151 38.742188 12.572266 38.742188 12.572266 L 35.236328 14.996094 C 44.091432999999995 21.21816 55.052161 29.822765 57.455078 37.628906 L 66.939453 33.650391 63.632812 30.410156 C 58.77426 27.95814 52.364322 23.85552 52.214844 19.224609 L 43.943359 11.123047 z"
  />
</svg>

<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="22 0 76 64">
  <clipPath id="clip2">
    <use xlink:href="#path2" />
  </clipPath>
  <use xlink:href="#path1" clip-path="url(#clip2)" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="22 0 76 64">
  <path id="res"
    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:0.26458332px;"
  />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если без плагинов то просто сделаем mask, смотрим

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="500" width="500">
   
   <defs>
    <style>
    #path1{
   fill:#fff;
    }
    #path2{
   fill:#000;
   }
 </style>
 
   <mask id="mask">
        <path id="path1" d="M 24.379464,51.504463 23.434524,23.156249 38.742559,12.572916 c 0,0 29.860118,-9.0714281 17.00893,0.755953 -12.851191,9.82738 13.229166,19.465774 13.229166,19.465774 z" />
     </mask>
   </defs>

   <path id="path2" d="m 32.883928,0.28869028 c 0,0 -15.686011,1.51190452 -8.504463,7.18154712 7.181546,5.6696426 50.270836,30.0491076 26.458332,42.3333336 -23.8125,12.284226 47.058036,14.174107 47.058036,14.174107 z" mask="url(#mask)"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Не то. Мне надо программно вычислить значение `d` у пересечения путей, а не отобразить это на экране.